# Angular Material 2 - Not rendering in full page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-material2

I am using [Angular Material 2](https://github.com/angular/material2) for my Angular 2 app. My dashboard page is not rendering full page in the browser. Attached is the screenshot of the above mentioned issue.

AppComponent - Template file:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

DashboardComponent - Template file :

```
<md-sidenav-layout>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav md-sidenav-over" (open)="list.focus()">
    <ul #list>
      <li> Item 1</li>
      <li> Item 2</li>
      <li> Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </md-sidenav>

  <md-toolbar color="primary">
    <button class="app-icon-button" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
      <i class="material-icons app-toolbar-menu">menu</i>
    </button>
    <span class="margin-left10"> Angular Material2 Portal </span>
    <span class="app-toolbar-filler"></span>
    <button md-button router-active [routerLink]=" ['Index']">
      Index
    </button>
    <button md-button router-active [routerLink]=" ['Home']">
      {{ 'HOME.TITLE' | translate }}
    </button>
    <button md-button router-active [routerLink]=" ['About'] ">
      {{ 'ABOUT.TITLE' | translate }}
    </button>
  </md-toolbar>

  <div class="app-content">
    <md-card>
      Dashboard Content Goes Here..!!
    </md-card>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <span id="footerText">Dashboard Footer</span>
  </footer>
</md-sidenav-layout>
```

DashboardComponent.ts:

```
import {Component, Inject, ElementRef, OnInit, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslatePipe} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';

console.log('`Dashboard` component loaded asynchronously');

@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  styles: [
    require('./dashboard.component.css')
  ],
  template: require('./dashboard.component.html'),
  pipes: [TranslatePipe]
})
export class Dashboard implements {
  elementRef:ElementRef;

  constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) elementRef:ElementRef) {
    this.elementRef = elementRef;
  }

  ngOnInit() {   
    console.log('hello `Dashboard` component');   
  }

}
```

Am I missing something here ?

Please refer : 
[Screenshot of my half-page rendered dashboard page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1sin.png)

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Take a look at this example, it renders fullpage https://github.com/kara/puppy-love

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the fullscreen attribute inside of the md-sidenav-layout tag.

This attribute will add these properties to the md-sidenav-layout:

```
[_nghost-oog-2][fullscreen] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

It's not very well documented quite yet that such an attribute can be added to the md-sidenav-layout since it is still in alpha. But [within](https://youtu.be/rRiV_b3WsoY?t=6m40s) this [preview](https://youtu.be/rRiV_b3WsoY) at ngconf they demonstrate some of what you can currently use from Material 2.